# ActionScript 3 Access Manually Added MovieClip Instance From A Class (not Document Class)

Tags: actionscript-3, reference, instance

If I have an instance named "btnExit" which I added manually to the Main Timeline, I can refer to it from my Document Class simply by typing its name, eg.

```
package{
    public class Engine extends MovieClip{

        public function Engine(){
            trace(btnExit.x);
        }
    }
}
```

But now I have an instance that is nested in another movieclip, and I want to access it from a class (not a Document Class).

Let's say I have "Menu" movieclip on my library.

Then I manually drag a "ButtonExit" button to the "Menu" movieclip timeline, I named the instance "btnExit", so "btnExit" is the child of "Menu" movieclip.

The "Menu" movieclip will be added dynamically by code to the main timeline.

Now I want to access the "btnExit" from "Menu" class file, so I write these codes.

The Document Class:

```
package{
    public class Engine extends MovieClip{

        public var menu:Menu;

        public function Engine(){
            menu = new Menu();
            addChild(menu);
        }
    }
}
```

The Other Class:

```
package{
    public class Menu extends MovieClip{

        public function Menu(){
            trace(btnExit.x);
        }
    }
}
```

But I got error #1009 (null object reference) for unable to access btnExit;

Can anybody help me, pleaseee?

Comment: Check your publish settings (file -> publish settings -> flash -> ActionScript 3.0 settings). Do you have "automatically declare stage instances" selected?

Comment: First comment received, thanks! :)Yes, I have it selected...and also have export for actionscript selected...

Comment: Check out [this article](http://www.developria.com/2010/04/combining-the-timeline-with-oo.html) I wrote on the topic.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship , I got some trick from your post..thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the instance of ButtonExit exists on every frame of the menu timeline and that it's instance named appropriately on every frame or write an if statement to only run your code if the Button is currently on the correct frame.

Every frame when the menu clip animates it's going to re instantiate everything on the frame, so if your second/third/fourth/etc frame doesn't have a clip named btnExit it's going to throw an error when the constructor is called for that frame.

Comment: If you don't need or want it to be on every frame, you can use a getter/setter pair to detect as the Flash player creates and destroys it, or listen to ADDED_TO_STAGE (see article link I posted above).

Comment: @Snukus Big thanks!!! It's solved by your answer **"instance named appropriately on every frame"**. I got error on my code earlier because I have 2 keyframe on "Menu" Movieclip, I only named the "btnExit" on 2nd keyframe, but on the 1st keyframe it's name is empty (I didn't notice it earlier).